How can I redirect error 500 to custom error page?
I'm trying to configure a custom error 500 page, because I'm programming an application with HTML + PHP (nothing special) and when I make a mistake in the code (I know the expected solution is not to have them, but I need this solution) the application crashes and returns an error 500 page predefined by the web browser.
To simplify the code, I have configured the simplified example in a virtual machine.

Ubuntu 22.04 with apache2 and php8.3 installed.
Index.php file inside /var/www/html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
    </body>
</html>


File 000-default.conf content:

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/prueba
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>

Output:
Hello World

Now, I force the error 500 changing the PHP text.
<?php echos '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>

Output:
HTTP ERROR 500

I have tried to add the following line to the 000-default.conf
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

But it's not working, the same screen is being showed.
But the same line for the error 400 works perfectly, redirecting to another page.
Maybe someone knows what can I do to find a solution and be able to redirect this error to another page? In addition, if I could also get the error message when I configure the directive display_errros = On inside php.ini file, it would be nice (not to show in the page, maybe to store inside a database with PHP).

It's echo and not echos.

See this answer. Basically, once Apache determines it isn't responsible for handling the file and turns itself over to PHP, it is done, and control does not come back. This is actually the behavior most people want, too. Assuming you configure your server correctly, you will probably never see a 500 level error from it, and if you have a router script in PHP you will probably never see the server's 404 template, either.

redirect error 500 is oxymoron. Redirect is 301 status code. And there could be only one status code. Either 301 OR 500. Either redirect or 500

@MartinZeitler That's the point, they were trying to trigger the 500

The best way to show a custom 500 error page is to define a custom error handler/exception handler. See example https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting
